# c++ Operator overloading in derivated class using pointers to base class

Tags: c++, embedded

I'm writing a **class** in c++ for an embedded system that behaves like a **variable of multiple types** (int, float, string, etc).
By means of subclasses that handle each type of value.
I need to do **operator overloading** for several operators like (+ - * / =! = + = - = == > < && ||!)
But perform the operations from a **pointer to the base class**.
How should I write these functions?
I'm testing something like this, but it does not do the sum.

```
class base
  { 
    public:
    virtual base& operator=(const base& other) {};
    virtual base& operator+(const base& other) {};
 ...
  }

class VarInt: public base
{
 public:
    int value;
    VarInt& operator=(const VarInt& other);
    VarInt& operator+(const VarInt& other);
}

class VarFloat : public base
{
 public:
    float value;
  ...
}

main(){
 ...
    base* varbase1 = new VarInt();
    base* varbase2 = new VarInt();
    *varbase1 = 1;
    *varbase2 = 2;
    *varbase1 += *varbase2;
}
```

Comment: For overloading operator functions need to have the exact same signatures. So usually this won't make much sense.

Comment: can a `VarInt` be added to a `VarString`? And if so, what should happen?
 Unrelated: This is not the sort of thing I would do in an embedded system. Normally you want a high degree of certainty of what you have in your hand

Comment: `VarInt` and `VarString` can not be added at the moment, but I want to leave everything ready to do so in the future.
I receive from the user interface a flexible script (written in a small c) that I must interpret and execute on an embedded system. For now it works very well interpreting customs functions, if statments, declartios, all bool algebra and all arithmetic operations, but with floating point variables. Right now I need to add the functionality with time variables, but I want to do so in the future to support the type of data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the assumption that when `VarInt` inherits from `base`, then:

```
virtual base& operator = (const base& other) {};
```

and

```
virtual VarInt& operator = (const VarInt& other) {};
```

are the the exact same thing. Unfortunately, **they are not**. What you do here, is hiding the previous method. When you `override` a virtual function you need to specify it the exact same way it was firstly declared, that is:

```
virtual base& operator = (const base& other) {};
```

The returned `base&` can be bounded to `VarInt` object, so we are safe here. The provided argument, being `const base&` can also be referenced to a `VarInt` object. Now you have to think about what you actually want to achieve here. Assuming that from your `base` class multiple classes with different functionalities can inherit, what will happen if you, for example, try to add `VarFloat` to `VarInt`? What is the expected result? Compiler error? Throwing an exception?

If you really wish to enable `operator =` to work with all the permutations of your inherited classes, then using `dynamic_cast<>` and `static_cast<>` will do the trick, however - keep in mind that if you happen to need to use casts, you might wish to rethink your design. Their usage is **not recommended**.

For a working example with `...cast` usage, see here:

```
class Base{
public:
    // mandatory for destructing the objects via pointer of a base class
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual Base& operator = (const Base& other) {};
};

class VarInt : public Base{
public:
    virtual Base& operator = (const Base& other) override
    {
        const auto ptr = dynamic_cast<const VarInt*>(&other);
        if(ptr != nullptr){
            // do whatever you need to - the *other* object is of a type VarInt!
            // use *ptr* to use *other* as VarInt
            return *this;
        } else {
            // do whatever you need to, when *other* is NOT a VarInt!
            // throw an exception? Add nothing?
        }
    }
};
```

Please keep in mind that **this is not recommended** for everyday usage - casts are a sign of a design flaw and should not be preferred

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. I do not like to use cast but I think this time I can not find a more elegant way to do it like this. I'm going to stage and googlear about this line that has new things for me like (`auto` and `dynamic_cast`).
`const auto ptr = dynamic_cast <const VarInt *> (& other);`
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Fernando `auto` is very useful and you should actually prefer to use it, especially when the type you want to create is long, i.e: `std::vector<int>::iterator`.